# Remove non breaking space (&nbsp;) from between elements using jquery

Tags: jquery, whitespace, html-entities

How can I use jquery to remove non-breaking spaces (nbsp) which appear between html elements?

So, for example, the following code is generated by a cms:

```
<div><span>content</span>&nbsp;<span>content</span></div>
```

I am able to target the elements using slectors.

The following page suggests an answer to remove normal whitespace, but not non-breaking spaces. [Remove whitespace and line breaks between HTML elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery)

Thanks

Comment: The current answers which remove text-nodes in [the thread you mention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery) should work on non-breaking spaces as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
var div = "<div><span>content</span>&nbsp;<span>content</span></div>";    
var newdiv = div.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4amF/1/)

Comment: Well this will remove only a single &nbsp;

Comment: this needs to be iterated for all the occurrences of &nbsp;

Comment: @ [anand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/380829/anand) I made an update, thanks ;)

Comment: I think, if the content is dynamic, this won't work, will it?