# jQuery/JavaScript - Trim white space/tab between two element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove non breaking space (&nbsp;) from between elements using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510646/remove-non-breaking-space-nbsp-from-between-elements-using-jquery)

How to write a script to trim white space/tab between two element?
For example,

```
<tr>       <td>A     </td>                <td>B   </td>      <td>C    </td>       </tr>
```

Convert to,

```
<tr><td>A     </td><td>B   </td><td>C    </td></tr>
```

For the example, the script should remove the white space/tab between first `<td>xxx</td>` element and second `<td>xxx</td>` element and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to do this? That white space has no effect on anything. Or do you mean that the code is actually displayed as text on the page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
function specialTrim(str){
    return str.replace(/>\s+</g,'><');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) with [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to match the text nodes inside your `<tr>` element:

```
$("tr").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```