# Using PHP to trim white space/tab for a string

Tags: php

According to the previous [**topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890712/jquery-javascript-trim-white-space-tab-between-two-element), I am going to trim white space/tab for a string in PHP.

```
$html = '<tr>       <td>A     </td>                <td>B   </td>      <td>C    </td>       </tr>'
```

converting to

```
$html = '<tr><td>A     </td><td>B   </td><td>C    </td></tr>'
```

How to write the statement likes `str.replace(/>\s+</g,'><');` ?

Comment: [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: @Phil: No. Don't use regex for HTML parsing.

Comment: @Tomolak In this case I'd say it's valid. The HTML is not being parsed anyway; it's simple string manipulation. Also, it was a direct answer to the question

Comment: @Tomolak ... further, were it an entire document, I'd definitely agree with you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?<=>)\s+(?=<)/', '', $str);
```

Less prone to breakage, but uses some more resources:

```
<?php
$html = '<tr>       <td>A     </td>                <td>B   </td>      <td>C    </td>       </tr>';
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($html);
$x = new DOMXPath($d);
foreach($x->query('//text()[normalize-space()=""]') as $textnode){
    $textnode->deleteData(0,strlen($textnode->wholeText));
}
echo $d->saveXML($d->documentElement->firstChild->firstChild);
```

Comment: Not a wholly robust solution, but input-dependent it may be sufficient in practice.

Comment: @Tomalak: indeed, somewhat iffy when talking sgml/html/xml of course, breakage possibilities a plenty. I'll offer an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/54ba6.php

result

```
<tr><td>A     </td><td>B   </td><td>C    </td></tr>
```

---

code

```
<?php 
$html = '<tr>       <td>A     </td>                <td>B   </td>      <td>C    </td>       </tr>'; 
$html = preg_replace('~(</td>)([\s]+)(<td>)~', '$1$3', $html); 
$html = preg_replace('~(<tr>)([\s]+)(<td>)~', '$1$3', $html); 
echo preg_replace('~(</td>)([\s]+)(</tr>)~', '$1$3', $html);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, could you advise what is the meaning of "~" in "'~(</td>)([\s]+)(<td>)~'" and "$1$3"? thanks

Comment: @Charles: Substitution. Take a look at the `preg_replace` manual page, and read a book on regular expressions.

Comment: @Charles PHP can use other characters besides the forward-slash as regular expression delimiters. It's useful if your pattern contains forward slashes (as in this case) as you don't need to escape them

Comment: @genesis Why capture the whitespace in a character class?

Comment: @Phil: Good question. It's redundant and genesis you've done this before!