# How do I write a regex expression saying 'and NO whitespaces'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was wondering how I would write a regex expression which says 'and NO whitespaces'.I need to implement this into the following if statement, see below:

```
$('#postcode').blur(function(){
    var postcode = $(this), val = postcode.val();

    if((val.length >= 5) && (*******)){ 
       postcode.val(val.slice(0, -3)+' '+val.slice(-3)).css('border','1px solid #a5acb2'); 
    }else{ 
       $(this).css('border','1px solid red'); 
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
&& (!val.match(/\s/))
```

`match` return `null` if there are no spaces (or at least one space), so you can use it as a condition.

Comment: If you really want to, you can combine the length check into the regex using `if(val.match(/^\S{5,}$/))` (note the upper-case S), but I'm not sure it's better.

Answer (score 1):

```
&& (val.indexOf(" ") == -1)
```

Note: Regex shouldn't be used if other options are readily available.

Comment: True, but `\s` also checks for tabs and newlines. Usually people refer to `" "` as "space" and the rest as "whitespace", but it is a better solution for normal spaces.

Comment: Good point. If this is only a single-line edit control, `space` is the only reasonable whitespace. However, if it's a textarea, there can be tabs, and linebreaks, and whatnot (these can also be pasted into a text input field from clipboard). Regex is actually reasonable here, as it matches any kind of whitespace.

Comment: @Kobi, @Piskvor: you are both correct. Combination of " ", tabs, newlines with all all their nice `\r`, `\n` variants can make whitespace matching problematic. In that case, regex is the best solution, but my answer is based on OP's question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Would [cleaning the whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery) before line 3 of your code help? (probably less intrusive)

Answer (score 1):

You can do both in the same regexp (guessing postcode is digits).

```
('1234567').match(/^\d{5,}$/) // ['1234567']
('1234').match(/^\d{5,}$/) // null
('12 34').match(/^\d{5,}$/) //null
('123 4567').match(/^\d{5,}$/) //null
```

so instead of:

```
if((val.length >= 5) && (*******)){
    //code
}
```

use:

```
if(val.match(/^\d{5,}$/)) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: I've just posted something similar in a comment. You may want `\S` instead of `\d`, depending on possible values.