# IE 8 remove line break between nodes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, whitespace

Ok i have a list of HTML nodes which should be inline with no spacing between them. The problem is, that the nodes are written from a CMS and therefore will come with all sorts of linebreaks and spaces. Therefore I'm removing the spaces with JS using the method descibed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery). The problem is, however, that in IE (not 9) the white spaces isn't part of the childrens list of the parent node, rendering the method useless in IE. However IE 7 (or at least IE 9 emulating IE 7) ignores the linebreaks, so that one is in the clear. That leaves IE 8 as the troublemaker. I discovered that the line break is actually a part of the `outerHTML` and that a simple reset of the `outerHTML` did the trick - like so:

```
node.outerHTML = node.outerHTML
```

However this will reset the node intirely and therefore removing all events and other settings on the node, which isn't really any good.

So my question is now: Is there a way to remove that linebreak from the nodes outerHTML whitout resetting the node? I've tried with zoom: 1, but to no avail. Hope anyone has any experience with this.

The HTML is more or less like this:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't have to be `<div>` it should be able to handle any tag. The CSS is pretty simple and goes something like this:

```
.items { white-space: nowrap; }
.items .item { display: inline-block; background: red; height: 150px; width: 180px; }
```

and IE (6-7(8)) style is like this:

```
.items .item { *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
```

i know that it is possible to "remove" that space via CSS like this:

```
.items { word-spacing: -0.33em; letter-spacing: -0.33em; }
.items .item { word-spacing: normal; letter-spacing: normal; }
```

but I find this to be an ugly hack that sometimes screw things up. So since I'm already manipulating the elements via JS, then I just hoped to remove the spaces via JS.

A little preview of what i meen:

[No spacing should appear between the squares http://tokimon.dk/stackoverflow/display-inline-spacing.png](http://tokimon.dk/stackoverflow/display-inline-spacing.png)

Comment: @Tokimon can you post sample HTML that your CMS is throwing? Can use that as test case. :)

Comment: I added the HTML, but as it's not yet implemented in the CMS the HTML is pretty straight.

Comment: @Tokimon - Wait.. you mean remove line breaks or remove *empty elements*? There's big difference between those two.

Comment: @Tokimon Is this by any chance what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/jBH5D/1/

Comment: I meen removing spacing between inline elements, that appear when the elements isn't inline int the HTML. So no... not empty elements, just spaces/tabs/line breaks between tags. I wish it was just empty elements as that would be easy.

Comment: @Tokimon you mean that here http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/jBH5D/1/ you want all words to appear next to each other without any space at all?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an IE box model problem. Do you have this meta tag in your HEAD?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Comment: Sorry m8. I already have <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> in the <head> section. It seems as general IE problem, but i really have no clue why the space is eliminated in IE 6+7. And just for the record i use the HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 0):

From quick test, what you want can be achieved with pure CSS - just have all "items" float:

```
.items .item { float: left; background: red; }
```

Updated test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/jBH5D/4/

Comment: Yeah i know... But then i have to specify a width for the container, to prevent the items from wrapping underneath each other, which i hoped to avoid.

Comment: @Tokimon you can easily set width using client side code according to current document width if you want it relative or something like that.

Comment: i know.. but then i have to recalculate the width each time a node is added or removed. kinda sucks and is resource consuming :)