# IE 9 changes style of tables element after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, internet-explorer-9

What I am trying to do is show list of dates and user is able to select them (checkboxes are with postback) when users select dates he can enable\disable and after update `monthListView.DataBind();` So the main problem is with style I attached two images, one before selection 
[image: before]
and other after selection
[image: after]

As you can see, problem is that some values go to new column, but in source they are same. How to fix this IE9 problem ? Tested with chrome, firefox and works fine. And always same values go out of their table. And it doesn't matter which value I select.

After:

```
<tr class='enabledTrue'>

    <td>
        <span class="LayoutTemplateStyle"><input id="MainContent_monthListView_MonthState_CheckBox_46" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$monthListView$ctrl46$MonthState_CheckBox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$monthListView$ctrl46$MonthState_CheckBox\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /></span>
    </td>
    <td >
        <span id="MainContent_monthListView_MonthName_Label_46" class="LayoutTemplateStyle">November 2012</span>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Before:

```
<tr class='enabledTrue'>

    <td>
        <span class="LayoutTemplateStyle"><input id="MainContent_monthListView_MonthState_CheckBox_46" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$monthListView$ctrl46$MonthState_CheckBox" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$MainContent$monthListView$ctrl46$MonthState_CheckBox\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /></span>
    </td>
    <td >
        <span id="MainContent_monthListView_MonthName_Label_46" class="LayoutTemplateStyle">November 2012</span>
    </td>

</tr>
```

PS: Open images in new tab to see code clearly.

Comment: Those images are so small that they're rendered next to useless. Use the `code` format to post markup/code.

Comment: @duane right click, view image.

Comment: If you inspect that extra cell using Developer Tools (F12), do you see anything unusual, like an extra `<td>`?

Comment: Same problem as in link below with solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267014/ie9-table-has-random-rows-which-are-offset-at-random-columns