# IE9 is not displaying table properly

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have added a menu on the following page http://www.ltgear.com . it is displaying properly in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE9. The Images get out of align. Whereas its showing properly in Compatibility mode. I have searched a lot but couldn't find what causing this. Can someone help me in rectifying the problem?

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bug of IE9 with spaces between Tags?
More details here: [MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/e6f49d52-ec3f-47c5-802e-b80d1a58ed39/) or:
[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267014/ie9-table-has-random-rows-which-are-offset-at-random-columns)