# Ghost cell in IE9 with Repeater Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

IE9 Generate blank cell or you can say Ghost Cell, with ASP.Net Repeater control.
I try javascript regural expression. Render function to run reg. exp. but the page holds few update controls and generate error.

**Error: sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception the message
received from the server could not be parsed. ScriptResource.axd**

I try all the well known links for this error.
Please suggest me if you really have...

Thank You

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
      using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
      {
        base.Render(htmlwriter);
        string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();
         if ((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RemoveWhitespace") + string.Empty).Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          {
            //html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])\s{2,}(?=[<])|(?<=[>])\s{2,11}(?=[<])|(?=[\n])\s{2,}", string.Empty);
            html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=<td[^>]*>)(?>\s+)(?!<table)|(?<!</table>\s*)\s+(?=</td>)", string.Empty);
            html = html.Replace(";\n", ";");
          }
         writer.Write(html.Trim());
      }
```

**another Solution is, but fail for Repeater**

```
var expr = new RegExp('>[ \t\r\n\v\f]*<', 'g'); 
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(expr, '><');
```

Comment: is it possible to remove blank space between </td> <td> when Repeater control create new row .... I don't know how .... any one have idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Repeater control directly (before it's written to the page and rendered by IE) and remove the cells based on their index.

Comment: thanks ... but these cells are not defined by me they are generated by IE9 only ... no other browser do that

Comment: I just re-read your post.  Are you saying that IE is adding an extra cell to the table, or just an extra space between the TD tags?

Comment: Yes its IE9 Bug. Please look that,its look same.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805956/internet-explorer-9-not-rendering-table-cells-properly

Comment: but i have simple ASPX page with repeater control using C#. NO Jquery, No Ajax

Comment: Whitespace between tags [inside of tables] should be ignored and no browser should be interpreting that as an extra cell.

Comment: Do you have a sample we can see?

Comment: Yes you are right no browser should interpret but IE9 create that with Table generate Dynamicly... Pls look this like my problem is same as that..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805956/internet-explorer-9-not-rendering-table-cells-properly

Comment: I have one soloution for that but its no reliable all the time.that is remove space between </td><td> at Designing but what if another developer use Ctrl + E,D....

Comment: It certainly shouldn't matter. I've seen hundreds of spaces and line breaks in the middle of tables and they still generate correctly.

Comment: This thread is more specific about a solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267014/ie9-table-has-random-rows-which-are-offset-at-random-columns

Comment: Thanks Dave, But I already try to do that, if I go through Regex show js error which i writen in my question.

Comment: Without seeing some output HTML to work with, it's tough to troubleshoot remotely.  But one thing I noticed is that they did the HTML scrubbing on the client side whereas you're trying to do it on the server.  Maybe give it a try using jQuery or good old fashioned JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove spaces between "< /td >" and "< td >".

Answer (score 0):

Found a very **useful** script to **prevent unwanted cells** in your html table while rendering in **IE9 browser**.

```
function removeWhiteSpaces()
{
   $('#myTable').html(function(i, el) {
      return el.replace(/>\s*</g, '><');
   });
}
```

This javascript function you should call when the page loads (i.e. onload event)