# Table cells shifting in IE9

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-9, cell

I am experiencing a very odd problem, but it only happens in Internet Explorer. Please refer to the image attached. (Sorry, I have been asked to blur the content as it is not yet live).

[image: table with misplaced cell]

Basically I have a long table. Half way through the table, one of the rows indents by just one cell. In a process of elimination, I have stripped back the content bit at a time and found

- All HTML is correct. There is no additional cell inserted. If you look in the developer panel, the first cell is selected, and likewise the first cell is selected in the actual table.
- The problem still occurs if I remove all CSS, so it is not styling related
- The content of each cell is just plain text and links, nothing complicated going on.
- This only happens when run from a server. If I view the source and save it to my desktop, opening in the same browser shows the cells as they should be. i.e. not indented
- If I remove any HTML before the indented cell, even some element not part of the table (a banner advert at the top of the page for example), the problem moves to another row.  the more code I remove, the more the problem moves higher up the page.
- As the problem moves up the page, i found that it is not limited to the first cell. Sometimes a cell in the middle of the row indents across by one
- Eventually, if I remove enough HTML code, the problem moves so high up the page that it disappears.
- The same problem happens on different servers, not just one.

Now I understand that nobody is able to help with a solution without me passing the code (and even if I did, you probably wouldn't experience the problem as it only occurs when run from a server), but is anyone aware of any problem/bug with IE(9) or anything else that may be contributing to this? I have been asked to give an explanation and am at a loss.

Comment: ...and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267014/ie9-table-has-random-rows-which-are-offset-at-random-columns

Comment: Thanks. I did not find those posts before.