# asp.net mvc html table gets corrupted after ajax call in IE 8, IE9, but works fine in other browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, jquery, html-table

I have a problem with html table that is fetched from server with ajax call: sometimes some of the rows in the table that is fetched from a server are rendered like this:

```
---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------
|   |   |   |   |       |
-------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
```

or

```
---------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------
|       |   |   |   |   |
-------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------
```

No colspan is present in the HTML retrieved from the server.

I am using asp.net mvc 4 in my project.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide all the code you can. Looking at your nice ASCII pictures does not really help in giving you clues about what might be wrong.

Comment: I can provide you with a html retrieved from server, but it is a simple html like <table><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr>...</table>. Note that the number of rows in my table is 100, I didn't notice that this issue occures when I have 20 rows in the table.

Comment: After a lot of search and trial hours I found the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805956/internet-explorer-9-not-rendering-table-cells-properly

I tried to remove all whitespace between end and begining of TD. It helped. This seems to be a bug in IE9.

Thanks!