# How to remove child element and spaces using jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

How to remove child element and spaces using jquery?

I have the following content:

```
<div class="sectionA"> <p>sfadfafdafdafdaf</p>  </div>
```

If I do:

```
$(".sectionA *").remove();
```

I get this:

```
<div class="sectionA">   </div>
```

How do I remove the spaces after removing the `<p>` child element?

Comment: try `$(".sectionA").empty();`

Comment: Here is a great script I have used before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) method, which does just what you described:

> This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements,
>   but also any text within the set of matched elements. This is because,
>   according to the DOM specification, any string of text within an
>   element is considered a child node of that element.

Example:

```
 $(".sectionA").empty();
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LF3j7/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Place an empty string inside it:

```
 $(".sectionA").html('');
```

Comment: agreed, since you are wanting the <p> tags removed as well.