# Jquery remove line breaks on enter key press

Tags: jquery

I have a keyup function on text area. When user press enter, cursor is going to next line and calculating white space.How do I remove it ?

Here is my code.

```
data.keyup('#id',function(e)
                   {

                       code= (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                         if (code == 13) { 
                                var xyz = $("#test").val();
                                xyz.length;
                             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try simple way like this

```
 if (code == 13) 
 {
                var xyz = $.trim($("#id").val()).length
                alert(xyz);
 }
```

Comment: :This is working but say when user presses back space continuously and hit enter, it is not working, it is calculating the space.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.cleanWhitespace = function() {
    textNodes = this.contents().filter(
        function() { return (this.nodeType == 3 && !/\S/.test(this.nodeValue)); })
        .remove();
    return this;
}


$('selector').cleanWhitespace();
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: :Should I add both the things in my jquery.

Comment: yes you need to add.In place of selector please specify your id