# jquery - removing IE's "Empty Text Nodes"

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have an issue w/ IE where I've got loads of 'Empty Text Nodes' in my `tr`.  If I run

```
$('#myTr').children().length
```

and

```
$('#myTr').find('td').length
```

I get the same value, which means that these nodes don't register with jquery.  The `:empty` selector comes back with nothing.

On top of that, if I remove these nodes manually from the IE debugger my format changes, so there's something material going on in there.

Here's what I see in the IE debugger (IE 8, btw):

[image]

Any ideas?  This is driving us nuts..

Comment: What's the problem with the empty text nodes? That is, why do they bother you and/or interfere with your goals?

Comment: I get wacky formatting (intermittently!) with them in there.  When they're manually removed, the formatting is fine.

Comment: If text nodes are a problem you can even set the font-size to 0px for the tr and then set them to whatever your font size is normally for the tds.  I use this on elements I style using display:inline-block.  (that is of course if you're using fixed font sizes)

Comment: You cant select text nodes with `$()`. You can do `$('#myTr').contents().length`

Comment: I love down votes with no comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer here:

[Remove whitespace and line breaks between HTML elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery)

There is a bug in IE9 that was causing my issue:

http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2013/01/internet-explorer-9-ie9-table-white.html

Answer (score 1):

HTML is whitespace agnostic, so it *shouldn't* matter that there are empty text nodes. I suspect you have a slightly different issue which happens to be resolved by removing the text nodes.

For example, manually removing the text nodes may force a reflow or repaint of the document which corrects a rendering bug. Or maybe messing with the nodes in the debugger triggers [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) on the parent (speculation).

Comment: Not exactly right. For example in CSS3 the pseudoselector :empty considers empty text nodes as well.