# Use JQuery to minify HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am using asppdf to create a PDF from HTML.

It looks like your HTML needs to be in a single line with all whitespace removed, before its passed to the **ImportFromUrl** method, this is an example from the support site:

```
str = "<HTML><TABLE><TR><TD>Text1</TD><TD>Text2</TD></TR></TABLE></HTML>"
Doc.ImportFromUrl str
```

Currently my HTML is pulled in from an external page & it's all formatted, so i need it to be like the above example. Can I use jQuery to do this?

Reference http://www.asppdf.com/manual_13.html#13_5

Comment: Who is the "Your" in this example? Where you say "Your HTML"?

Comment: @George What about text node containing any space?

Comment: The function name is `ImportFromUrl`. Shouldn't you pass a url and not a HTML string to it?

Comment: @Vohuman nope it also accepts HTML too

Comment: "Starting with Service Release 1.6.0.8, the ImportFromUrl method allows you to specify an HTML string directly via the first parameter (URL). The string must contain the sub-string <HTML or <html to be recognized as a direct HTML feed and not a URL."

Comment: Your reference doesn't make any mention of all the text being on one line, or with all whitespace removed. What happens when you pass in your HTML as it is?

Comment: @OllyHodgson I get a parse error if I pass in an unformatted string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regular expression for spaces only:

```js
var HTML = "<h1>hh ee</h1>     <h2>heyy  heyyy</h2>";
document.getElementById("after").innerText = HTML.replace(/>[ ]+</g, "><");
document.getElementById("before").innerText = HTML;
```

```html
<h1 id="before"></h1>
Becomes
<h1 id="after"></h1>
```

And this for tabs, new lines and spaces:

```js
var HTML = "<h1>hh ee</h1>    <h2>heyy  heyyy</h2>";
document.getElementById("after").innerText = HTML.replace(/>[\n\t ]+</g, "><");
document.getElementById("before").innerText = HTML;
```

```html
<h1 id="before"></h1>
Becomes
<h1 id="after"></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks thats the regex I was looking for!

Comment: not the best solution if you have `<strong>test</strong> <strong>test2</strong>` since you suddenly end up with `testtest2` instead of `test test2`.

Comment: @RandomUser http://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/ understands HTML, because it's based on an actual HTML parser. Slightly more heavyweight than your regex though :)

Comment: @RandomUser if i knew an answer, i would've given it. I'm just pointing out a possible flaw :-)

Comment: My HTML is pretty much static & only the innerHTML changes on various elements, so I am happy with the solution from @RandomUser

Comment: HTML.replace(/>[\n\t ]+</g, "><").trim() will remove whitespaces from start and end too.

Answer (score 3):

i use regex `"someHtml".replace(/\n\s+|\n/g, "")`. It's not perfect but it will keep the content intact an delete most of the unnecessary white spaces.

```js
var dom = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
$("body").text(dom.replace(/\n\s+|\n/g, ""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  lorem ipsum
</div>



<div>
  more text
</div>   <div>
  test 123
</div>
```

Comment: can you also explain what it removes. also i think you should consider adding new line character check from different OS refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805125/how-to-remove-all-line-breaks-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this
Code:

```
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks but this is replacing all whitespace inside the tags too, like this...<!DOCTYPEhtml><metacharset="utf-8"/><head><linkhref="/css/site.css"rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: Please refer the link:   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery)