# remove text before and after an html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I use jQuery or plain JavaScript to remove the spaces before and after the `<nospc/>` tag in the code below?  (I realize I could simply remove the spaces manually, but sometimes it's convenient to have spaces and line breaks in the HTML that are not rendered.)

```
<div>
    <img src="" /><nospc/>
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

In a perfect world `<nospc/>` would remove all white space before and after the itself, and `<nospc> ... </nospc>`  would remove all white space between the tag pair.

Comment: Is `<nospc/>` really a tag?

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: $("nospc").empty() will remove all content inside nospc, but I don't see the open nospc tag in your code above..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539367/remove-whitespace-and-line-breaks-between-html-elements-using-jquery

Comment: Rather than use a JavaScript approach, I would use the HTML comment approach. More info here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: @Shadowen, No I just made that tag up figuring that I could access it with jQuery or JavaScript.  @ItayB  There is no opening tag.  `<nospc/>` is both the opening and closing tag.  My goal is to remove the space on the web page that will be between the two images.

Comment: @epascarello - Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Maximillian - Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.contents()` , `.each()` `Node.nextSibling` , `Node.previousSibling` , `Node.textContent` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\s+/`

```js
$("div").contents().each(function(i, el) {
  if (el.nodeName === "#text" && el.nextSibling 
       && el.nextSibling.nodeName === "NOSPC" 
     || el.nodeName === "#text" && el.previousSibling 
       && el.previousSibling.nodeName === "NOSPC" 
     || el.nodeName === "NOSPC") {
         el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, "")
  }
});

console.log($("div").contents())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
    <img src="" /> <nospc> </nospc> 
    <img src="" />
</div>
```